# Produce a chart from histograms

Tags: r, gnuplot

I have two histograms superimposed in an R file. All the parameters are set equal (bin size, x-scale and y-scale). I would like make a chart where the x-axis rapresents the same variable of the histograms, but in the y-axis, the proportion of the y-axis of the two histograms.

**Example:**

In a generic bin that represents the range [X_0, X_1] I have twenty events for the first histogram and ten events for the second histogram. So the chart must have in that point the value  (X_0+X_1)/2  for the x-axis and 10/20 in the y axis.

How can I do this with R or gnuplot?

Comment: And what would GNU R be? (I've heard it called GNU S, but never GNU R)

Comment: @nico R is part of the GNU project, so it is not unreasonable to call it GNU R, but R would suffice.

Comment: @Gavin: I guess... it was just the first time I heard it and sounded strange, that's all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be a 0 in the denominator

```
> many <- rnorm(1000)
> few <- rnorm(100)
> mh <- hist(many, plot=FALSE)
> fh <- hist(few, breaks=mh$breaks, plot=FALSE)
> ph <- fh
> ph$density <- fh$counts/(mh$counts+0.001) #you have to deal with a 0 denominator
> plot(ph,freq=FALSE)
```

This is for R. I don't know "gnu" R.

Comment: Thanx, but can you explain better what does it means please? :)

Comment: The code is very explicit. I dont think words help. It takes the histogram (binning is what important here) data (plot=FALSE) from one (many) applies the binning to the histogram of the other (few). Then puts the ratio of one/other into the density part of the histogram that gets plotted.